# Changing the value of a style variable with Javascript [EDITED]

Tags: css, styles

*** START EDIT ***

All of the following (after this [EDIT]) remains correct. This [EDIT] brings to light **WHY** am I trying to change the value of a style variable with Javascript. And this important **WHY** questions whether I **should be** trying to change the value of a style variable to begin with. Maybe I should be trying something else?

This crucial WHY centers on the fact that my basic layout (all relative positioning) includes a basic `<audio>` tag at the very bottom. This `<audio>` tag is very undisciplined in that, with pinch zooming **on a real iPhone**, this `<audio>` moves up and covers the other relative objects that precede it.

I've buried below my description of this movement, but I thought this movement should be highlighted at the very beginning.

I want to emphasize that this unexplained vertical movement is on a real iPhone. On the **emulated iPhone, via the Developer Menu**, `<audio>` does not exhibit this obnoxious behavior ... with Safari, or Chrome, or Firefox or Opera.

So, what is the other something I should be trying?

[I have purposely left all the stuff below for the sake of integrity of this problem description **and** for the sake of **everybody's very hard and patient work** trying to help me]

*** END EDIT ***

Eventually, my goal is to change the value of a style variable with Javascript. In the meantime, I cannot get a simple `alert(...)` to show anything. So, I thought I would start with this basic stuff, and build from there (I present that alert way down below).

**HTML:**

```
<div id="caroler">
as sung by an unknown Caroler
</div>

<div id="audioWrapper">
<audio class="aSongControl" controls preload="auto">
    <source src="..." type="audio/mp4">
</audio>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#caroler {
    text-align: center;
    font-size:  1.70em;
    color:      blue;

    padding-bottom: 1.0em;
}

/* do the positioning within the Wrapper */
#audioWrapper {
    display: block;     /* center ... */
    margin:  0 auto;

    width:  90%;
}

.aSongControl {
    width:  100%;        /* fill the Wrapper */

    font-size: 120%;     /* for non-support text ... */
    color:     #990099;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
/* we'll let the css DOM take care of the initial rendering */
window.onresize = function() {
    theCaroler = document.getElementById("caroler");
    theSong    = document.getElementById("audioWrapper");
    alert(theCaroler.style.color);
}
```

Please note that eventually I wish to dynamically change the top of the `#audioWrapper` so that it moves up and down with window resizing.

(yes, I know regular CSS layout will do this easily, but the dang `<audio>` tag plays havoc with window resizing ... like overlapping what's above it with window resizing. SO I thought (??) I would move the `<audio>` tag with Javascript)

**But, in the meantime, with all the above, I cannot get the simple `alert(theCaroler.style.color)` to show anything.** Rather basic stuff that I apparently do not understand (yet).

The next step will to find out what theCaroler.style.bottom is because .bottom is not specified in the CSS.

Which opens up another significant tidbit; namely, I have read that such `object.style.parmName` retrievals only work with in-line styles, **not** styles imported from external style sheets **and not** from styles embedded in the `<header>`.

So, it's fairly obvious that I am wallowing in an ocean of ignorance and I need your help.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `getComputedStyle` if you want to get the current style? (regardless, nothing's stopping you from *assigning* to a style property)

Comment: That's because `theCaroler.style.color` is looking for a style tag (inline styles), yet all your styling is in CSS. It's impossible to access your CSS via the style attribute.

Comment: So are you trying to prevent the `<audio>` tag from moving around when the browser is resized?

Comment: Resizing does not shift the audio tag and it shouldn’t. It’s the pinch zooming on a real iPhone that makes it shift. CMD-+ on a desktop doesn’t move it, just pinch zooming on a real iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

First question:
If you are trying to change the style of something with Javascript, then you need to get the id or class, just like you did with the variable.

`var x = document.getElementById('something');`

Then you need to use that variable and add `.style.backgroundColor = 'green';`. You can change backgroundColor and green to whatever you need. Just know that if in the CSS tag there is a dash, such as in `background-color` then in JavaScript you need to remove the dash and capitalize the second word, to make it a compound word, since JavaScript doesn't like dashes, except for in strings.

`var x = document.getElementById('something');
x.style.backgroundColor = 'green';`

Second question:
You were going in the right path by using `alert();`. The only thing is you need add `window.` before it.

`window.alert('This is an alert');`

Third question:
I'm assuming you're trying to change the bottom border. In CSS, that would be `border-bottom: solid;`, and you can change solid to whatever border you need. [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-bottom.asp) can tell you some of the ways. In JavaScript, it would be `x.style.borderBottom = 'solid';`

I hope I have helped, and if there is something you don't understand or isn't working, then just comment on this answer! If it does help, please accept this answer and up-vote it. Thanks!

Comment: What I am trying to do is to force my <audio> tag to stay where it is, namely at the bottom, not inching up with pinch zooming and subsequently covering the objects above it. All objects in my DOM are positioned relative. And this inching up only happens on a real iPhone. I have tried to position this <audio> = absolute, but this inches up also.